# Why object dont send itself as first argument

Tags: python

While learning classes staked on this problem. Trying to create a new class with method and send it some arguments, in literature I see "self" as first argument in methods, but in my try not.

```
class smf():
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def check(self, A, B, C):
    print(A)

a=smf
a.check(input(), input(), input())
```

Program expects 4 arguments, why? Where am I wrong?

Comment: `a=smf` should be `a=smf()`.

Comment: They way you wrote it, you never create an instance. a.check(..) is the same as smf.check(..), i.e. calling the class' function withou an object reference, thats why you're effectively only handing it 3 arguments.
As mentioned by @kevmo314, create an instance via smf().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in comments, `a=smf` should be `a=smf()`. But why do you get that error?

In Python, `instance.method(args...)` is kind of syntactic sugar for `class.method(instance, args...)`, which explains why the first argument of methods is the instance itself, usually called `self`. And by doing `a=smf`, `a` is another reference to *the class itself*, so you are actually calling the method in the `class.method(instance, args...)` kind of way missing the `self` instance.